# How to Handle Table 'db_9_925283.vessels2' doesn't exist Error if table does not created

Tags: mysql, node.js

SQL Query:
Error:
How to Handle Table 'db_9_925283.vessels2' doesn't exist Error if table does not created in database.

Requirement:
if I want to query multiple tables, but one of the table does not created in database. I need to ignore that table and return result from existing tables.

Example code :

```
-- table vessels

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vessels` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vessel_id` int(8),
  `signal_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `data` float(4),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `vessels` (`id`, `vessel_id`,`signal_name`,`data`) VALUES
  ('1', 1, 'temparature',10.0),
  ('2', 1, 'vibration',20.0),
  ('3', 1, 'heat',30.0),
  ('4', 1, 'vibration2',NULL),
  ('5', 1, 'vibration3',50.0),
  ('6', 2, 'vibration4',NULL),
  ('7', 2, 'vibration5',60.0),
  ('8', 2, 'vibration5',70.0),
  ('9', 2, 'vibration5',NULL);

-- table vessels1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vessels1` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vessel_id` int(8),
  `signal_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `data` float(4),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `vessels1` (`id`, `vessel_id`,`signal_name`,`data`) VALUES
  ('1', 1, 'temparature',10.0),
  ('2', 1, 'vibration',20.0),
  ('3', 1, 'heat',30.0),
  ('4', 1, 'vibration2',NULL),
  ('5', 1, 'vibration3',50.0),
  ('6', 2, 'vibration4',NULL),
  ('7', 2, 'vibration5',60.0),
  ('8', 2, 'vibration5',70.0),
  ('9', 2, 'vibration5',NULL);
```

Query:

```
select id,vessel_id,data,signal_name
from `vessels`
where data is not null
AND
vessel_id = 1

union all

select id,vessel_id,data,signal_name
from `vessels2`
where vessel_id = 2
AND
data is not null
```

Response of Above Query:

> Table 'db_9_925283.vessels2' doesn't exist

SQL Fiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/297c72c

Comment: `vessels2` should be `vessels1`. That's the name of the second table you created.

Comment: There's no way to ignore an error like this. You could write a stored procedure that creates dynamic SQL by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to see which tables exist, and leaving out the ones that don't exist.

Comment: @Barmar sir Barmar, if dynamic SQL is used in a sproc, should we try to make a single complete query using UNION , or create a temp table and populate it table by table ? The latter one seems less prone to errors but more likely to invokes race condition ?

Comment: Or you can query the list of available tables from your app and dynamically assemble the query there, not in a stored proc.

Comment: What the dynamic SQL does depends on the specific needs of the application. Populating a temp table may improve performance but you'll be working with a snapshot of the data.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually "wrong" to have multiple tables with identical schemas.  When combining these two tables (and adjusting the `SELECT`), the typo will magically go away.